# Enlarging an Imageview on click

Tags: android, eclipse, android-imageview, android-image

Hello Stackoverflow friendo's. I'm just wondering if someone can assist me.

I've created an app which holds a lot of images, the images are currently pretty small but I want them to expand once they're clicked. Is there any way of doing this?
My app holds about 50 xml and the same in classes. But it holds about 100 images, is there any simple way to do this?

An example of my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#808080"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="499dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/Logo"
     android:layout_width="120dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="255dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
     android:src="@drawable/logov2" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="84dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-90dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/seatedcablerows"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="32sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/blackline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/blackline" />

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/textView1"
                   android:layout_width="95dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                   android:text="@string/startphase"
                   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                   android:textColor="#ffffff"
                   android:textSize="16sp" />

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textView2"
                      android:layout_width="121dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
                      android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                      android:text="@string/middlephase"
                      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff"
                      android:textSize="16sp" />

      <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/textView3"
                   android:layout_width="95dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
                   android:text="@string/endphase"
                   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                   android:textColor="#ffffff"
                   android:textSize="16sp" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="97dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/seatedcablerowstart" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                 android:layout_width="97dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/seatedcablerowmid" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                 android:layout_width="97dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="245dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/seatedcablerowend" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/blackline2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/blackline" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/seatedcablerowsdesc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/seatedcablerowsdesc"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/seatedcablerowsperf"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="238dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                     android:gravity="center"
                     android:text="@string/seatedcablerowsperf"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                     android:textSize="14sp" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/seatedcablerowscaut"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="64dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                     android:gravity="center"
                     android:text="@string/seatedcablerowscaut"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                     android:textSize="14sp" />

                 <ImageView
                      android:id="@+id/blackline3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/blackline" />

                                                            <!--Set 1 starts here  -->
                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/set1"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/set1"
                     android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                     android:textSize="25sp" />

                   <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/weight"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                     android:text="@string/weight"
                     android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                     android:textSize="16sp" 
                     />

                     <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/repititions"
                         android:layout_width="116dp"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
                         android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                         android:text="@string/repetitions"
                         android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                         android:textSize="16sp" />

                 <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/editText1"
                     android:layout_width="67dp"
                     android:layout_height="36dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                     android:background="#FFFFFF"
                     android:ems="10"
                     android:inputType="number"
                      >

              </EditText>

                 <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/editText2"
                     android:layout_width="67dp"
                     android:layout_height="36dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="-37dp"
                     android:background="#FFFFFF"
                     android:ems="10"
                     android:inputType="number" >

                </EditText>
                 <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/blackline2" />
                                                                <!--Set 2 starts here  -->
                   <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/set2"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/set2"
                     android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                     android:textSize="25sp" 
                     />
                   <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/weight1"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                     android:text="@string/weight"
                     android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                     android:textSize="16sp" 
                     />
                      <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/repititions2"
                         android:layout_width="116dp"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
                         android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                         android:text="@string/repetitions"
                         android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                         android:textSize="16sp" />
                            <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/editText3"
                     android:layout_width="67dp"
                     android:layout_height="36dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                     android:background="#FFFFFF"
                     android:ems="10"
                     android:inputType="number" >
                     </EditText>
                        <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/editText4"
                     android:layout_width="67dp"
                     android:layout_height="36dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="-37dp"
                     android:background="#FFFFFF"
                     android:ems="10"
                     android:inputType="number" >

                </EditText>

                   <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:src="@drawable/blackline2" />
                                                                        <!--Set 3 starts here  -->
                     <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/set3"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/set3"
                     android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                     android:textSize="25sp" 
                     />
                   <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/weight3"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                     android:text="@string/weight"
                     android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                     android:textSize="16sp" 
                     />
                      <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/repititions3"
                         android:layout_width="116dp"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
                         android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                         android:text="@string/repetitions"
                         android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                         android:textSize="16sp" />
                            <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/editText5"
                     android:layout_width="67dp"
                     android:layout_height="36dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                     android:background="#FFFFFF"
                     android:ems="10"
                     android:inputType="number" >
                     </EditText>
                        <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/editText6"
                     android:layout_width="67dp"
                     android:layout_height="36dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="-37dp"
                     android:background="#FFFFFF"
                     android:ems="10"
                     android:inputType="number" >
 </EditText>
                     <ImageView
                         android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:src="@drawable/blackline2" />
                                                                     <!--Set 4 starts here  -->

                          <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/set4"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/set4"
                     android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                     android:textSize="25sp" 
                     />
                   <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/weight4"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                     android:text="@string/weight"
                     android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                     android:textSize="16sp" 
                     />
                      <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/repititions4"
                         android:layout_width="116dp"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
                         android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                         android:text="@string/repetitions"
                         android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                         android:textSize="16sp" />
                            <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/editText7"
                     android:layout_width="67dp"
                     android:layout_height="36dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                     android:background="#FFFFFF"
                     android:ems="10"
                     android:inputType="number" >
                     </EditText>
                        <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/editText8"
                     android:layout_width="67dp"
                     android:layout_height="36dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="-37dp"
                     android:background="#FFFFFF"
                     android:ems="10"
                     android:inputType="number" >
 </EditText>

                                  <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/savebutton"
                             android:background="@null" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/QR"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="-60dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/qrscanner" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Java class:

```
package com.example.workplease;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.example.workplease_v2.R;

public class Seatedcablerows extends Activity {
ImageButton imagebutton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.seatedcablerows);

        AddListenerOnButton();
}

public void AddListenerOnButton(){
    final Context context = this;

    imagebutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.QR);

    imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Qrscanner.class);
                        startActivity(intent);  
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google has nicely explained [How to enlarge view on a touch](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html). You can use same technique for your image view also. 
Check the given link for full example code.

Comment: Yeah I just also found this, thank @Pratap Singh, will I have to create about 100 classes to store all the java in for the images? I'm kinda new to Java...

Comment: why 100 classes..? Just create one class that has zooming feature and use it for all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a fragment with a gridview that holds your images, just attach an onItemClickListener to them and when someone clicks the image, get the ID and pass it back to the activity which will get the image from where it is located using the id and set up a new fragment with a single ImageView; that will do it.

**EDIT**

After reading your question a second time, I think you might have to change the way you are doing it (up to you really)

Have two arrays to store the smaller images and the larger versions of the images respectively.

Now, use a fragment or just a regular view with a gridview in it to display all your images and then implement an a click listener to keep track of which image was clicked using the position argument.

After knowing which image was clicked, just pass back the position to the activity and use that position to load the bigger image from the second array of larger images and display it in an imageview with the preset dimensions/ width/height respectively.

This is what I think will help solve your problem.

**NOTE** In order to pass back the position of the clicked image, you just need an interface  in a fragment if you use a fragment (then implement it in your activity), otherwise, you can just get the position from within the activity and do your next task there.

Comment: I'm neither using gridview or fragments to hold the images, do you know any other way of possibly expanding the images? @Eenvincible

Comment: Expanding images will involve scaling them which might mess up the resolution; You can however set their dimensions in the original views smaller than the real images and then to enlarge them, set their widths and heights as needed to enlarge them; You can display the image in a dialog or its own ImageView inside a fragment.

Comment: I don't really want to change everything. Do you think it'll be fine if I change all the imageviews to buttons, and follow the method found here?
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html#views
@Eenvincible