# how to display fullscreen image view onlclick

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, imageview, xamarin.android

Im fairly new to xamarin.android and i have an image view in a scroll view and I want to enlarge it on click. (display full image onclick like on mobile facebook) when the user clicks image I want it to open up in the full screen.How do I accomplish this?

ive done some research and couldn't find some useful threads.. any help would be appriciated thank you in advance.

heres my detailactivity class

```
private ImageView mtimg0, mtimg1, mtimg2, mtimg3, mtimg4, mtimg5;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.detailLayout);

        FindViews();


        Android.Content.Intent i = this.Intent;
        string iname = i.Extras.GetString("MTNAME");
        int iimg0 = i.Extras.GetInt("IMG0");
        int iimg1 = i.Extras.GetInt("IMG1");
        int iimg2 = i.Extras.GetInt("IMG2");
        int iimg3 = i.Extras.GetInt("IMG3");
        int iimg4 = i.Extras.GetInt("IMG4");
        int iimg5 = i.Extras.GetInt("IMG5");

        mtimg0.SetImageResource(iimg0);
        mtimg1.SetImageResource(iimg1);
        mtimg2.SetImageResource(iimg2);
        mtimg3.SetImageResource(iimg3);
        mtimg4.SetImageResource(iimg4);
        mtimg5.SetImageResource(iimg5);
    }

    private void FindViews()
    {
        tmtname = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.mtname);
        mtimg0 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mtimg00); 
        mtimg1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mtimg01);
        mtimg2 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mtimg02);
        mtimg3 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mtimg03);
        mtimg4 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mtimg04);
        mtimg5 = FindViewById<ImageView>Resource.Id.mtimg05);            

    }
}
```

**EDITED**

here's an example of item in my list view where I'm getting all of my images

```
 class MountainsData
  {
    public static List<Mountain> MountainList = new List<Mountain>()
        {
        new Mountain()
            {
                MtName = "ALTO PEAK",
                Masl = 1332,
                Difficulty = 6,
                Island = 2,
                MtImg00 = Resource.Drawable.altopeak,
                MtImg01 = Resource.Drawable.altopeak1,
                MtImg02 = Resource.Drawable.altopeak2,
                MtImg03 = Resource.Drawable.altopeak3,
                MtImg04 = Resource.Drawable.altopeak4,
                Location = "ORMOC, LEYTE",
                JumpOff ="Lake Danao National Park, Ormoc",
                Description ="LLA: 11.1061 N, 124.7097 E, 1332 
            }
```

and in my list view activity.. here's how I'm passing each item to my detail activity... and to recieve it in my detail activity I'm using the code above(in detailactivity class.. the first code above in this question)

```
   private List<Mountain> mMountains;
   private void OpenDetailActivity(int pos)
    {
        mt = mMountains[pos];
        i = new Intent(this, typeof(DetailActivity));

        i.PutExtra("IMG0", mt.MtImg00);
        i.PutExtra("IMG1", mt.MtImg01);
        i.PutExtra("IMG2", mt.MtImg02);
        i.PutExtra("IMG3", mt.MtImg03);
        i.PutExtra("IMG4", mt.MtImg04);
        i.PutExtra("IMG5", mt.MtImg05);
        i.PutExtra("MTNAME", mt.MtName);
        i.PutExtra("LOCATION", mt.Location);
        i.PutExtra("JUMPOFF", mt.JumpOff);
        i.PutExtra("DESCRIPTION", mt.Description);
        i.PutExtra("BACKGROUND", mt.Background);
        i.PutExtra("ITINERARY", mt.Itinerary);
        i.PutExtra("PRACTICALITIES", mt.Practicalities);
        i.PutExtra("ATTIRE", mt.Attire);
        i.PutExtra("TTB", mt.Ttb);

        StartActivity(i);

    }
```

what I want to happen inside detailactivity is when I click the imageview.. display it in a full screen but i cant find a way to pass the string properly.. thank you in advance :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enlarging an Imageview on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409920/enlarging-an-imageview-on-click)

Comment: Or just create a new Activity for Fullscreen View. Pass the imageurl or path with an intent to the new Activity.

Comment: If don't want to leave your Activity, you can also show it in a Fragment...if you need a custom solution for your project share what you did so far :-)

Comment: @Ben you mean fullscreen fragment? is that what u mean? is that even possible?

Comment: @KeithJustine yep, Just a sec (I'm on the phone) and I'll write you the line of code you may need

Comment: @Ben yayy! thank you so much sir Ben :D will search/read about fragments while waiting

Comment: @KeithJustine It might take 2-3 hours before I can get home, in the meanwhile try: `Dialog dlg = new Dialog(this, Android.Resource.Style.ThemeBlackNoTitleBarFullScreen) ` , If it doesn't fit your needs I'll provide a more elaborate answer :-) (don't forget to call `dlg.Show()` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution with a DialogFragment:

**Your fragment_dialog.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:minWidth="2000dp"  
    android:minHeight="2000dp"> 
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:src="@drawable/aaa"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**Your MyDialogFragment.cs**

```
public class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment
{
    private ImageView imgView;
    static public MyDialogFragment newInstance()
    {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
        return f;
    }

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetStyle(DialogFragmentStyle.NoTitle, Android.Resource.Style.ThemeBlackNoTitleBarFullScreen);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);

        imgView = v.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img);
        //Get int and set it to the ImageView
        int imgPassed = Arguments.GetInt("imgId");
        imgView.SetImageResource(imgPassed);

        return v;
    }
}
```

**From your ItemSelected or Click event**

```
        FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();

        //Declare String and get the Id
        string imgName = "bbb"; //Change with the name of the image you want to pass
        int imgId = Resources.GetIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", PackageName);

        //Pass it with the Bundle class
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.PutInt("imgId", imgId);
        newFragment.Arguments = bundle;

        //Show the Fragment
        newFragment.Show(ft, "dialog");
```

**EDIT:**
I used the Bundle class as one of the possible ways to pass data from Activities to Fragments. Works fine for me.

Another way to have the same result is simply using another Activity and intents, you can find everything you need here: [Passing Data Between Activities](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/)

Comment: hello sir ben/ thank you for your answer.. it helped a lot.. can you show me how to pass string from activity? because it doesnt seems to receive the right data..

Comment: @KeithJustine I edited the post, if it works for you make sure to mark the question as answered. If you need more help let me know :-)

Comment: hello sir ben sorry for late reply, just back from vacation.. your answer is very helpful but I'm still having a trouble on passing string.. it doesnt seems to recieve the right data.."  int iimg5 = i.Extras.GetInt("IMG5");" this line of code is how im passing the string from my listview to detail activity.. just wondering how can I pass it in dialog fragment?

Comment: @KeithJustine You shall not use an Intent anymore...if I understand your code. "IMG5" is the name of the image you want to show. if so you can use `int imgId = Resources.GetIdentifier("IMG5", "drawable", PackageName);` to take the int identifier of your image. Then you have to use the bundle class to pass it as shown in **From your ItemSelected or Click Event**

Comment: still doesnt work :( IMG5 is the name of string in my " i.PutExtra("IMG5", mt.MtImg00);" which is coming from array. i just want to display the image in full screen but it seems like its not retrieving the right string.. any workaround for this one sir @Ben

Comment: how can I set image source in dialogfragment?? .

Comment: What is the literal name of your image in your drawable folder? Moreover, from what i understand there is an Activity from where your "IMG0,IMG1,etc." come from, can you edit your question so i can edit mine with the details you need? Let me know ;-)

Comment: hello sir ben I already figured the answer to my question.. now.. I'm wondering.. is it possible to implement slide to next picture in dialog fragment.. again.. thank you for your help :D

Comment: @KeithJustine Yes, it is possible... sorry for the delay but it has been a busy week at work. Please wait till tomorrow and I'll direct you to the solution ;-)

Comment: @KeithJustine I read back your question, You should ask a different question for the swipe implementation, but i think there are a lot of good tutorials and examples on the internet